# Angular2 how to pass data throught router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm devolping a web application using `Angular v2.0.0`. Since I have a sub-navigation in my app I would like to pass some data to a sub-page, that loads its own component, through the `<router-outlet>`.

As i can see on Angular2 documentation I can reach this purpose if i include a sub-page directive in the main component template, but this isn't what i need.

I'd like to use code like the following:

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '/', redirectTo: '/one' },
    { path: '/one', as: 'One', component: OneComponent },
    { path: '/two', as: 'Two', component: TwoComponent },
    { path: '/three', as: 'Three', component: ThreeComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**main.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'main',
    templateUrl: 'main.component.html'
})

export class MainComponent {
    maindata: Object = {name:'jim'};
}
```

**main.component.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>   
<a [router-link]="['./sub1']">One</a> | 
<a [router-link]="['./sub2']">Two</a> | 
<a [router-link]="['./sub3']">Three</a>   
<hr/>  
<router-outlet [data]="maindata"></router-outlet>
```

**one.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'one',
    inputs: ['data'],
    templateUrl: 'one.html'
})

export class OneComponent {
    @Input() data;
}
```

**one.component.html**

```
<h2>{{ data.name }}</h2>
...
```

How to do this?

Comment: You have to use a service

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data directly into a component through the route using resolvers. First step is to register the resolver:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ExampleService,
    {
      provide: 'foo',
      useValue: () => {
        return {
          msg: 'Something something something'
        };
      }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then make use of it in the routes:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  { 
    path: '/one',
    component: OneComponent,
    resolve: {
      foo: 'foo'
    }
  }
];
```

The final thing to do is to make use of it in the component:

```
@Component()
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  foo;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foo = this.route.snapshot.data['foo'];
  }
}
```

See this [ThoughtRam](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html?utm_campaign=NG-Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_source=NG-Newsletter_169) post for more

Comment: Your solution is unidirectional and doesn't deal with obejcts.

Comment: @smartmouse Well you said you want to "pass some data to a sub-page." You didn't say you want to manipulate it and pass it back. Also - of course it deals with objects. You get an object passed to the component which you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass argument, for example argument id for 'user' link would be written as 'user/:id' and you can take this argument later. Also, you can use @Input() and @Output() annotations

Comment: I mean passing data, not just an ID